# how to set the Date to the 1st Friday of the Current Year in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to set the date to the 1st Friday of the Current Year in JavaScript.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
const firstMonth = "01"
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var firstDay = new Date(currentYear, 0, 1);
var weekday = firstDay.getDay();
while (weekday != 5) {
  if (weekday < 5) {
    weekday = weekday + 1;
  } else {
    weekday = weekday - 1;
  }
}

var friday = new Date(currentDate.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 6)).toUTCString();
console.log(friday)
```

Comment: if you have access to npm modules, I would suggest using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/). There you can call `.startOf("year").startOf("week").add(4, "days")`

Comment: @LouisWilke don't recommend moment js, they themselves advise to but use it anymore. There are more lightweight and better alternatives. See project status link on their page.

Comment: @cloned Thanks, that's news for me! I'll check out the alternatives

Answer (score 0):

So first Friday of the current year can be in last year according to your code example? That would only work if you mean first Friday in the first week of the year

Here is first Friday of this year using your loop:

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
const newYear = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0); // make a date that is not near midnight anywhere
let day = newYear.getDay()
while (day != 5) {
  console.log(newYear.toString())
  newYear.setDate(newYear.getDate() + 1);
  day = newYear.getDay();
}

console.log("Friday", newYear.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var firstDay = new Date(currentYear, 0, 1);
var weekday = firstDay.getDay();
while(weekday != 5)
{
        firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate()+1);
        weekday = firstDay.getDay();
 }
```